# how to make online chating functionality in iphone?

Tags: iphone, web-services

I want to make Social Community app in iphone.Just like i want to develope online chating functionality. I have list of users who are logged into my application.My application is iphone application.How can i do that?any tutorial or sample code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios this link will help you somewhat

you can also try this [link](https://github.com/dmendels/chatDemo)

this sample demonstrates how QuickBlox Chat API works. [VIDEO TUTORIAL](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=SncQaJBBW_0)

It allows to organize chat in room & chat 1 on 1.

It shows how to: - Organize chat between 2 users - Organize chat in room

You can download this code sample [here](http://quickblox.com/developers/How_to_add_Chat_to_your_application)

just googled the things and you will find lots of more useful tutorial..

Comment: sir this is i think facebook or twitter app.But i want to make social community app.In this app i want to add some online chat funtionality.so please give me an idea

Comment: http://attila.tumblr.com/post/21180235691/ios-tutorial-creating-a-chat-room-using-parse-com ..this link will help u

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you to go for push notification. Cause I have used it in one of my app. And it's really good rather than using other.

Comment: that also a good option...!!!

Comment: ok thank you.But i want to make social community app.In this app i want to add online chat funtionality.so give me an idea sir.Thank you.

Comment: As you mention you are making an social app that's mean there is a concept of friends or what ever you have a branch of online people in your app for chatting. So you could have their device token. Now from sender throw a push to that device token (people you want to chat) and APNS will send your message to that device. And from receiver side caught the notification and show it where ever you want to show.